# Looping through an array of values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, count

I made a database for a pil of information we receive in a .csv. I then have a form set up to show all of the data using a Match & Index formula in a nice table which is was we send out. I'm trying to make my export of these tables easier using For Each in VBA. Current code is

```
Sub ExportAllSheets()

Dim DB As Workbook
Dim OSR As Worksheet
Dim EL As Worksheet
Dim SN As Range
Dim List As Range
Dim Name As Range
Dim x As String

Set DB = Workbooks("Database")
Set OSR = DB.Sheets("OilSamplingResults")
Set EL = DB.Sheets("ExportList")
Set List = EL.Range("A2:A100")
Set Name = EL.Range("B2:B100")

x = InputBox("Enter File Name")

ScreenUpdating = False

For Each SN In List

EL.Range("A2").Copy OSR.Range("G5")
  OSR.Copy After:=OSR
    Sheets("OilSamplingResults (2)").Range("A1:BN45").Select
        Selection.Copy
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
         :=False, Transpose:=False
            Sheets("OilSamplingResults (2)").Move After:=Workbooks(x).Sheets("Master")
Workbooks(x).Sheets("OilSamplingResults (2)").Name = Workbooks("Database").Sheets("ExportList").Range("B2")
Workbooks("Database").Sheets("ExportList").Activate
ScreenUpdating = True

Next

End Sub
```

Workbook Database has the results page that I want to export, and an ExportList page. Column A is the serial number which drives my match formula on the results page. Copies the serial and pastes it in G5, which retrieves all data, copies the results page, and 'flattens' it by copying just the values back over. Moves the newly flattened sheet to the export file and renames it based on ExportPage column B value.

What I have currently works, but since I have A2 and B2 hard set in my loop, it gives me a 'that name is already taken' error. I'm at a loss how to get it to use A3 and B3...4.5.6 and so on.

I should also clarify that when I export a list of numbers, they all go to the same file. The next time I export will be a different file name, but again, the entire list to that one file.

I see a lot of people use Dim I as Integer and I + 1 and a count function, just never have done that before.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ExportAllSheets()

Dim DB As Workbook
Dim OSR As Worksheet
Dim EL As Worksheet
Dim SN As Range
Dim List As Range
Dim Name As Range
Dim x As String
Dim i As Long

Set DB = Workbooks("Database")
Set OSR = DB.Sheets("OilSamplingResults")
Set EL = DB.Sheets("ExportList")
Set List = EL.Range("A2:A100")
Set Name = EL.Range("B2:B100")

x = InputBox("Enter File Name")

ScreenUpdating = False

For Each SN In List
For i = 2 To 100
If EL.Range("A" & i) = "" Then GoTo SheDone
EL.Range("A" & i).Copy OSR.Range("G5")
    OSR.Copy After:=OSR
        Sheets("OilSamplingResults (2)").Range("A1:BN45").Select
           Selection.Copy
             Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,     SkipBlanks _
             :=False, Transpose:=False
                 Sheets("OilSamplingResults (2)").Move After:=Workbooks(x).Sheets("Master")
                    Workbooks(x).Sheets("OilSamplingResults (2)").Name =Workbooks("Database").Sheets("ExportList").Range("B" & i)
                        Workbooks("Database").Sheets("ExportList").Activate
ScreenUpdating = True
Next
Next

SheDone:
    MsgBox ("Export Complete")
End Sub
```